# Are there any good command line tools for compressing/decompressing snappy?

Tags: command-line

I have some [snappy](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/) files that I'd like to be able to compress/decompress on the command line. I didn't see any obvious tools, is there's something standard that people use for snappy?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that this is an Ubuntu specific question. You should rather ask the authors of this tool via e-mail or no their forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a gem that I found long back on the arch forums, before you use it you should have `7zip` and `unrar` or other tools to handle the formats you need to extract.

```
# File extractor
# usage: extract <file>
extract ()
{
  if [ -f $1 ] ; then
    case $1 in
      *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tar.gz)    tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1   ;;
      *.rar)       unrar x $1     ;;
      *.gz)        gunzip $1    ;;
      *.tar)       tar xf $1    ;;
      *.tbz2)      tar xjf $1   ;;
      *.tgz)       tar xzf $1   ;;
      *.zip)       unzip $1     ;;
      *.Z)         uncompress $1;;
      *.7z)        7z x $1      ;;
      *.snz)       snunzip $1      ;;
      *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
    esac
  else
    echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
  fi
}
```

To use it, you must add this to your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` after that is done you can use `extract` to decompress all sort of archives from the command line. The syntax is `extract name-of-archive`

You can use it with snappy too, you need to install [this](https://github.com/kubo/snzip) however before it'll work.

Comment: The question is about a specific file format, snappy, which your answer doesn't mention.

Comment: @sierrasdetandil  have added the details to make it work with snappy too, the objective of my answer was to share a tip that I personally dind very useful and can be extended to virtually any file format.

Comment: I understand, I was just pointing out that it didn't answer the question. I've removed my downvote now that it does.

Comment: @sierrasdetandil Fair point!

Comment: uugh, why not start the answer with install `snzip`. you mention `7zip` and `unrar` which have nothing to do with snappy.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly [feature request #34](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/issues/detail?id=34) in the issue tracker of Snappy. See the comments of December 3 for a Python command line version available on Github.